# Cannot find module "qfi" for running JdeRobot drone_cat_mouse exercise from source

Tags: python, ros, robotics

I want to run JdeRobot drone_cat_mouse on my Ubuntu 20.04. I'm using ROS Noetic and has faithfully followed [these installation instructions](https://github.com/JdeRobot/drones/blob/noetic-devel/installation20.md). Everything it told me to test was working properly.

When I first ran roslaunch drone_cat_mouse.launch, there was an import error for teleopWidget and sensorsWidget which I fixed by using relative imports. Then I had an error `No module named qfi`.

[image: No module named qfi]

Unlike teleopWidget and sensorsWidget, I couldn't find the qfi module in the [JdeRobot/drones source code.](https://github.com/JdeRobot/drones) So I googled it, and the only relevant result that popped up was [this](https://gsyc.urjc.es/pipermail/jde-developers/2017-April/004421.html), which led to [this link](https://github.com/JdeRobot/base/issues/738). They said to:

`sudo touch /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qfi/__init__.py`

But I ran that command and this happened!

[image: qfi module no exist]

Not even pip has a "qfi" module!

[image: y u no qfi?!]

So I thought to check [JdeRobot's entire repository.](https://github.com/search?q=org%3AJdeRobot%20qfi&type=code) Turns out it was in JdeRobot/base, and that repo is not maintained anymore!

After further digging, there was [this issue](https://github.com/JdeRobot/RoboticsAcademy/issues/847) which basically tells us forget about it and move to the web release! But I can't, circumstances forced me to use the source code option (deliverables are drone_cat_mouse.world and my_solution.py, it's impossible for me to get the former in the docker web version and the latter's format is different between the source code version and the web version).

In a nutshell, how do I fix this `qfi module` problem so that I can run the exercises from source [like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZCDixH1RV8) [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwAGndG8nx0) [people](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eadm9I4ZDso)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just stupid, as usual. all I need to do was clone https://github.com/JdeRobot/ThirdParty, get the qfi module, copy it to
~/catkin_ws/src/drones/rqt_drone_teleop/src/rqt_vel_teleop/ and replace all qfi imports with its relative import version. All common sense

No errors in terminal, gazebo runs, but somehow the rqt widget for drone vision never appears.

[image: why]

Forget it, I'm giving up on this dumpster fire of a program.

Edit: I did another fresh install, followed the steps, noticed troubleshooting for qfi which required qmake, but same end result

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to launch `drone_cat_mouse` there is an issue with the namespace of the RQT widget that occurs when you try to launch it.
Namely, the topics that exist for `drone_cat_mouse` are prefixed by `cat/` or `mouse/`. But RQT will try to access these topics without the prefix and run into an error. Alternatively, since you have a local install, you can try to run the code manually by running

```bash
python my_solution.py
```

Just make sure the change the area where the DroneWrapper class was called in the following manner:

```py
HAL = DroneWrapper('drone', 'cat/')
```

Here `'drone'` is the name of the node you are creating and `'cat/'` is the namespace given to the DroneWrapper Class.